# Django server not starting after importing python project as package

Tags: python, django, machine-learning, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a deep learning python project named 'predict'. I want to use it in my django views so I use `from predict.Prediction import Prediction` where *predict* = root directory of python project, *Prediction.py* is the file that I need to use. Whenever I run *python manage.py runserver*, I get the error as:
[Server not starting issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6sY0.png).

I have the **init** file in the root folder [predict (python project) structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNAxo.png).

I am stuck on this from long and clueless as to what is the issue.

Comment: A [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help.

Comment: The screenshot doesn't show the command being run. Do you have a `manage.py` file and are you running that command? Settings file?  For context, would viewing a sample django app structure help? e.g. [Django 4 by example's first chapter](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Django-4-by-example/tree/2a3380d/Chapter01/mysite)

Comment: @TonyN I am running 'python manage.py runserver' and then the server never starts . If I remove the *import predict* line from my views, the server starts

Comment: At this phase, I think the next step would be more effort on your side to [improve the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There's not enough information (yet!)